# Trouble Attaching File Programmatically to Email in Windows Metro App C#/XAML using Share Charm

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, charms-bar

I'm simply trying to attach a file named **Document.pdf** in the **DocumentsLibrary** to an email using the Share Charm.  My code below works perfectly on the Local Machine:

```
    private async void OnDataRequestedFiles(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<IStorageItem> shares = new List<IStorageItem>();
        StorageFile filetoShare = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync("Document.pdf");

        if (filetoShare != null)
        {
            shares.Add(filetoShare);
            filetoShare = null;
        }

        if (shares != null)
        {
            DataPackage requestData = e.Request.Data;
            requestData.Properties.Title = "Title";
            requestData.Properties.Description = "Description"; // The description is optional.
            requestData.SetStorageItems(shares);
            shares = null;

        }
        else
        {
            e.Request.FailWithDisplayText("File not Found.");
        }
    }
```

But when I run the *exact same code* on a Windows Surface Tablet, I get the dreaded **"There's nothing to share right now."** on the right in the Charms flyout area.

Here's a little more background to help:

- I'm **not** looking to use a File Picker...I know the exact file I'm looking for
- I've enabled the Documents Library Capability in the manifest
- I've added a File Type Association for pdf in the manifest
- and yes, the file does exist and is in the Documents Library
- an email account is properly setup in the Mail App on the surface
- I can successfully send text emails from the Tablet...just not emails with attachments

Like I said, this works on my Win 8 Development Machine as expected...just not on the Surface.  I'm wondering if the Surface has different file or folder permissions?

Thanks for the help...this is driving me CRAZY

Comment: Does this process work on your Local Machine, when you use a non admin account?

Comment: @AlSki - I believe there is some validity in your comment about using a non-Admin account (I have to write and store the PDF in a different directory)...thanks for pointing this out.  I've added an answer that works for the Admin account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out - the problem was that my Event Handler was **async** (so that I could use **await** to set the **StorageFile** variable).

I solved it by setting the **StorageFile** variable earlier in my code so that it was already available when the Event Handler was called.

I still have no idea why it worked on my development machine, but no on the WinRT surface...

Answer (score 2):

The handler can be an async method.  In this case, it is critical to use DataTransferManager.  Please refer to [the MSDN page specifically for this scenario](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh871371.aspx). For your convenience, the code from the page is copied to here:

```
private void RegisterForShare()
{
    DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, 
        DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareStorageItemsHandler);
}

private async void ShareStorageItemsHandler(DataTransferManager sender, 
    DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share StorageItems Example";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "Demonstrates how to share files.";

    // Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
    // we need to get the deferral first.
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();  

    // Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
    try
    {
        StorageFile logoFile = 
            await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\Logo.png");
        List<IStorageItem> storageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
        storageItems.Add(logoFile);
        request.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItems);       
    }
    finally
    {
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

It is critical to place the following statement before any async method is called:

```
DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have half a second to get the whole job done (getting the file, attaching...etc.). If the half-second deadline occurs you'll get this "driving crazy" message. Consider implementing some resumable logic and replace the message with "the attachment is being prepared please try again in a few seconds" (or else).
Your WinRT device might be just slower than your development machine. The latter just does the job before the deadline...